# BadKeyError: Invalid string key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm getting this error when trying to create a script that would serve images from GAE Datastore.

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/datastore_types.py", line 379, in __init__
    raise datastore_errors.BadKeyError('Invalid string key %s.' % encoded)
BadKeyError: Invalid string key 5066549580791808.
```

With this code:

```
class ImageHandler(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        greeting = db.get(self.request.get('id'))
        if greeting.image:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
            self.response.out.write(greeting.image)
        else:
            self.error(404)
```

This class was created from the [image documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages) on GAE

Comment: why aren't you using `webapp2.RequestHandler` as suggested? also, in your templates are you using something like `key = {{ the_key }}`, with spaces around the `=` ? if yes, remove them. Or show us the view/template/url that generates that key

Comment: You haven't shown how you're generating the `id` value that you're passing in the request.

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo the MainHandler class inherits from the webapp2.RequestHandler class.

Comment: I generate the url like 'www.myapp.com/image?id=123'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5066549580791808 isn't a key, it's an id.

You need to use `SomeModel.get()`, `db.get()` requires the entire key, which includes the Model and path.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use the [Blobstore API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/)

In that way you are able to serve the images with different sizes on-the-fly using the images API:  [Transforming images from the Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/#Transforming_Images_from_the_Blobstore)

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.api import images
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

    class Thumbnailer(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            blob_key = self.request.get("blob_key")
            if blob_key:
                blob_info = blobstore.get(blob_key)

                if blob_info:
                    img = images.Image(blob_key=blob_key)
                    img.resize(width=80, height=100)
                    img.im_feeling_lucky()
                    thumbnail = img.execute_transforms(output_encoding=images.JPEG)

                    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/jpeg'
                    self.response.out.write(thumbnail)
                    return

            # Either "blob_key" wasn't provided, or there was no value with that ID
            # in the Blobstore.
            self.error(404)
```